# Telnet test for Apache Flume agent through NGINX load balancer

Tags: nginx, proxy, load-balancing, telnet, flume

I implemented a flume agent with these properties:

```
agent1.sources.r1.type = netcat
agent1.sources.r1.bind = localhost
agent1.sources.r1.port = 41414
agent1.sinks.k1.type = logger

agent1.channels.c1.type = memory
agent1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
agent1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

agent1.sources.r1.channels = c1
agent1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

I run it with

```
bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ --conf-file ./conf/flume.conf --name agentX -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

then I connect to this agent thorugh telnet as follows:

```
>telnet localhost 41414

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Hello World!
OK
```

All goes fine, I send text and my agent shows it as logging information:

```
2016-03-16 11:58:41,172 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.LoggerSink.process(LoggerSink.java:94)] Event: { headers:{} body: 48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21 0D          Hello World!. }
```

What I want to do now is to run two agents, put an nginx load balancer proxy between these agents and my telnet client, and try the same experiment, so that the telnet connection sometimes goes to the port 41414 (agent1) and sometimes to 41415 (agent2). My load balancer already works for a couple of python sockets I tested earlier, so the configuration file should be ok:

```
http {

    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
    upstream localhost {

        server localhost:41414;     
        server localhost:41415;     

    }

    server {
            listen          41410;
            location / {
                proxy_pass      http://localhost;
            }
    }
}
```

I connect to this proxy using:

```
telnet localhost 41410
```

then i start sending text. Instead of sending it to one of my flume agents, I receive the following response through the telnet window:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?